# Add new column in the Dataset with condition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am new in pandas and python, but I want to add new column that collect all row data and paste it in new column for example:

```
df_final = pd.read_csv('df_final.csv')

House_No = df_final['House_No_'].copy()
Street = df_final['Street'].copy()
City = df_final['City'].copy()
District = df_final['District'].copy()
Postl_Code = df_final['Postl_Code'].copy()

df_final['Full_Address']=(House_No +' , '+ Street +' , '+ City +' , '+ District +' , '+ str(Postl_Code))
```

the output is :

[image]

when the House No is null the new cell become null .. find it in row 7,8 and 9 in the image. 
how can ignore the null cell and just take the rest of the roe ??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you expect it to look like?

Comment: `df.apply(', '.join, axis=1)`?

Comment: @johnashu Hi I would like to make it ignore any null value and just from any columns and just copy paste the rest of values.

Comment: @Yo_Chris Hi it is not working

Comment: @AbuOmair you have to convert all columns to a string...see my answer for additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# sample data
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=(5,5)), columns=list('abcde'))
df.iloc[2, 0] = np.nan
# use np.where with join
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['a'].isna(), df.iloc[:, 1:].astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1),
                         df.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1))



     a  b  c  d  e          new_col
0  6.0  9  6  1  1  6.0, 9, 6, 1, 1
1  2.0  8  7  3  5  2.0, 8, 7, 3, 5
2  NaN  3  5  3  5       3, 5, 3, 5
3  8.0  8  2  8  1  8.0, 8, 2, 8, 1
4  7.0  8  7  2  1  7.0, 8, 7, 2, 1
```

or if you do not care if the nan is in the final output simply do:

```
df['new_col1'] = df.astype(str).apply(', '.join, axis=1)

     a  b  c  d  e         new_col1
0  6.0  9  6  1  1  6.0, 9, 6, 1, 1
1  2.0  8  7  3  5  2.0, 8, 7, 3, 5
2  NaN  3  5  3  5  nan, 3, 5, 3, 5
3  8.0  8  2  8  1  8.0, 8, 2, 8, 1
4  7.0  8  7  2  1  7.0, 8, 7, 2, 1
```

Comment: Hi in this example: in row 2 column a contains NaN and the rest of the row did not take.
My condition is just ignore that NaN and take the rest of the row.

Comment: I am sorry I missread your question. I thought you wanted NaN if house_no was nan. I will updated

Comment: @AbuOmair see update. I used iloc to skip the first column if nan so you will only join columns `1:`